# Convert xml to custom class using lambda linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

Attempting to parse an xml document to a custom class which I have created. I have successfully figured out how to parse the document, but for some reason I am having to do it into an `IEnumerable` instead of just a single instance of my custom class. Much easier to just show the code than explain in depth, so please see code snippets below.

### Working Code

```
IEnumerable<Ping> ping = xmlDoc.Descendants("PING_SEND").Select(p => new Ping
    {
        TRAN_ID = (string)p.Element("TRAN_ID"),
        MILOC = (string)p.Element("MILOC"),
        TRANDATE = (string)p.Element("TRANDATE"),
        TRANTIME = (string)p.Element("TRANTIME"),
        COUNTRY = (string)p.Element("COUNTRY")
    });
```

### Which Results in having to use...

```
foreach (Ping p in ping)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRAN_ID", p.TRAN_ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MILOC", p.MILOC);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SITE_REF", "");
}
```

... when adding parameters to insert into the database. What I have tried (and need) is something that would be more in the vein of this...

### Desired Code idea

```
Ping ping =(Ping)xmlDoc.Descendants("PING_SEND").Select(p => new Ping
    {
        TRAN_ID = (string)p.Element("TRAN_ID"),
        MILOC = (string)p.Element("MILOC"),
        TRANDATE = (string)p.Element("TRANDATE"),
        TRANTIME = (string)p.Element("TRANTIME"),
        COUNTRY = (string)p.Element("COUNTRY")
    });

//... Other operations and database functions...

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRAN_ID", ping.TRAN_ID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MILOC", ping.MILOC);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SITE_REF", "");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is a call to `First()` or `Single()` or whatever - to say that you only want *one* result (the first or only result - other options are available):

```
Ping ping = xmlDoc.Descendants("PING_SEND").Select(...).First();
```

Basically, the issue is that after `Descendants(...).Select(...)` you've got a *sequence* of `Ping` references, whereas you only want one.

If there might actually be multiple `PING_SEND` elements - or none - you really need to think about what you want to do in that situation. LINQ provides various methods to help, depending on your requirements:

- `First`
- `Single`
- `Last`
- `FirstOrDefault`
- `SingleOrDefault`
- `LastOrDefault`

The `OrDefault` methods allow you to handle the case where there are no results.